How to download the Trello card attachment to a Google Drive folder using Zapier. The app returned “unauthorized permission requested”
Good afternoon. I have a problem with uploading files attached to Trello cards to Google Drive.
Ideally, I need to upload only the last attached file. The File field in the Upload File module of Zapier gives an error - Failed to create a file in Google Drive.
The app returned “unauthorized permission requested”. The disk connection is active and stable. I think the problem is in this field. Here is an example of the link I want to use to download the attached file -  Link to the attachment (https://.trello.com/1/cards/66a97cd3ca3d333bd531923a/attachments/66a9aaf0921b230c6173bf71/download/Viktor_Follow_up_.docx)
Maybe someone has already dealt with this. I will be grateful for your help.
I did not find the answer in the Atlantis documentation.
I tried to insert various links and IDs into the attached file. Searching for the answer on the Internet did not help.

The problem was that Trelo's board was private, and this prevented access to the attachment. I created a new board, made it public and everything worked)

The error you are seeing is a result of the file not being publically accessible. What I mean is that the URL you shared in the post requires you log into Trello in order to access the file.  Your Zap needs to be able to access the file from Trello without having to log in.
You may be using a Trello trigger which supplies the actual file object.  When you are setting up your Google Drive step, you can look for a field coming in from Trello which is the attachment and says (exists but not shown).  If you use this field then your Google Drive step should work.
If you try this and are still having issues I would encourage you to reach out to Zapier Support when logged in using our contact form (https://zapier.com/app/get-help). We would be more than happy to continue working with you to find a solution to your problem.
Ted - Zapier Support

Thank you for your response. The problem was that the Trello board was private, and this prevented access to the attachment. I created a new board, published it, and everything worked)
